# Is there a way to modify and integrate the apps located in the packages/apps/ subfolder of the AOSP automotive source using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-source, android-automotive

I am in charge of the application layer in AOSP and I am aware that typically, after developing an app, the APK is inserted into the AOSP source to make it a system app.

What I am curious about is how to modify the apps already included in the packages/apps/ subfolder of AOSP. It's a painful task to create apps like Contacts or Dialer from scratch, so I'd like to modify and use the apps under packages/apps/.

However, the apps included in AOSP (packages/apps/) are not gradle-based projects, so I cannot use Android Studio.

How can I modify these apps using Android Studio and reintegrate them with the AOSP source?

I've looked up official documents but they've only confused me.

If possible, I'd like to build in Android Studio as mentioned above and only include the APK in the AOSP source.

Can you tell me how to modify and integrate the apps under packages/apps/ typically?

Answer (score 1):

https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/unbundled_apps/integration

There is guide documents for unbundled apps of Android Automotive. There are Dialer and Media apps integration guide too. Hope it helps.